# Как из строки взять первую букву и подставить в ординарные кавычки?

Tags: java

Есть строка `"pvp"`, мне нужно взять из неё первую букву, т.е. `p`, далее подставить в ординарные кавычки `('сюда')`. Как это лучше сделать?

```
public static final StateFlag PVP = new StateFlag("pvp", 'p', true);
```

Comment: В чем суть загвоздки?! Вам надо из строки достать первый символ?

Comment: Да, а дальше подставить в char.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот:

```
    String str = "pvp";
    char c = str.charAt(0);
```

Comment: не знаю за что минусовал кто-то, но: -В чем суть загвоздки?! Вам надо из строки достать первый символ? -Да, а дальше подставить в char. По-моему, все верно.